# check if textbox exists vba (using name)

Tags: vba

I am using Ms-Access and I created a userform which has a number of Textboxes on it. The boxes are named: Box1, Box2, Box3 ...

I need to loop through all boxes, but I don't know which is the last one. To avoid looping through all userform controls I thought of trying the following:

```
For i =1 To 20

If Me.Controls("Box" & i).value = MyCondition Then
    'do stuff
End If

Next i
```

This errors at Box6, which is the first box not found. Is there a way to capture this error and exit the loop when it happens.

I know I could use `On Error` but I 'd rather capture this specific instance with code instead.

Thanks,
George

Comment: I'm suprised any of the iterations work on that `Conrtols` object :P

Comment: @MacroMan - its probably User Defined :}

Comment: Isn't this a really bad way to use forms in Access?  That you're looking for the last control suggests you're adding text boxes to the form at run-time which I was always under the impression that it was a bad idea (in Access) as you need to open the form in design mode before adding the control, add code so you can use the button (rather than a class hooked into the control) - isn't this question pointing out that the form design could be better, or there may be a better solution?

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook - I need may forms with a similar initial design to pull data from the same place. But very different on how this data will be analysed. Each box will take a user defined identifier. So this is part of a module that will be used on many forms. The number of boxes can range from 5 - 15 across different forms. So I thought of giving them the same name (wont be Box in actual implementation). I guess I could always have 20 boxes on all forms and hide the inactive ones, but I would rather not. `Me.Controls` will also have to change eventually, but is irrelevant at the time being

Comment: If the form design is similar enough I'd probably use a single form with the 20 boxes and write all the analysis code to work on just that form with some kind of identifier telling it which analysis to perform.  So most of the code won't actually sit in the form, it'll be in normal modules which are called from the form.  Or a Switchboard style form - have a single button on a continuous form connected to a table holding the button text and arguments.

Answer (score 5):

A [`Controls`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445317(v=vs.60).aspx) collection is a simplified collection of controls (obviously) and share a same order as a placement order of controls.

First of all, even a creatable collection object lacks methods such as `Exists` or `Contains` , hence you need a function with error handling to checking/pulling widget from a collection.

```
Public Function ExistsWidget(ByVal Name As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
        ExistsWidget = Not Me.Controls(Name) Is Nothing
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

If you really doesnt like *"ask forgiveness not permission"* option you can pull entire ordered collection of your textboxes (and/or check existance by name in another loop with similar logic).

```
Public Function PullBoxes() As Collection
    Dim Control As MSForms.Control

    Set PullBoxes = New Collection

    For Each Control In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf Control Is MSForms.TextBox And _
                Left(Control.Name, 3) = "Box" Then
                Call PullBoxes.Add(Control)
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Since names of widgets are unique - you can return a `Dictionary` from that function with (Control.Name, Control) pairs inside and able to check existance of widget by name properly w/o an error suppression.
[There's](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/) a good guide to `Dictionary` if it's a new information for you.

Anyway, no matter what object you choose, if user (or code) is unable to create more of thoose textboxes - you can convert this `Function` above to a `Static Property Get` or just to a `Property Get` with `Static` collection inside, so you iterate over all controls only once (e.g. on `UserForm_Initialize` event)!

```
Public Property Get Boxes() As Collection
    Static PreservedBoxes As Collection

    'There's no loop, but call to PullBoxes to reduce duplicate code in answer
    If PreservedBoxes Is Nothing Then _
            Set PreservedBoxes = PullBoxes

    Set Boxes = PreservedBoxes
End Property
```

After all, the last created `TextBox` with name `Box*` will be:

```
Public Function LastCreatedBox() As MSForms.TextBox
    Dim Boxes As Collection

    Set Boxes = PullBoxes

    With Boxes
        If .Count <> 0 Then _
                Set LastCreatedBox = Boxes(.Count)
    End With
End Function
```

I think that now things are clearer to you! Cheers!

*Note: All code are definitely a bunch of methods/properties of your form, hence all stuff should be placed inside of form module.*

Comment: Looping through all controls only when initialising the form is a good idea. You added a lot of info which is good for learning. But why not (for this purpose) abbreviate everything by just adding `MyBoxes = MyBoxes + 1` instead of `Call PullBoxes.Add(Control)`? `MyBoxes` could be a `Public Variable` or a hidden `Label` on the form.

Comment: @George, sorry, but what is `MyBoxes` variable? A `Long` variable representing a counter? If it is, then you can check a `Count` property of a Collection/Dictionary instead. If you're about make a `Public` collection instead of Property - it's up to you, there's no difference in behaviour with those two (but depends on where you would place your `Public` variable). If it's some sort of iterator/current index - then please eleborate for what reason do you need one?

Comment: I was asking if it was better to replace `Public Function PullBoxes() as collection`, with `Public Function MyBoxes() as integer`. `MyBoxes` would run when initializing the form and count the number of Boxes I have. Shortening everything to the `for each control in me.controls` loop. `Existswidget`, `getboxes` and `lastcreatedbox` would no longer be required.

Answer (score 2):

Long story short - you cannot do what you want with VBA.
However, there is a good way to go around it - make a boolean formula, that checks whether the object exists, using the `On Error`. Thus, your code will not be spoiled with it.

```
Function ControlExists(ControlName As String, FormCheck As Form) As Boolean
   Dim strTest As String
   On Error Resume Next
   strTest = FormCheck(ControlName).Name
   ControlExists = (Err.Number = 0)
End Function
```

Taken from here:http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1029435

To see the whole code working, check it like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestMe()

    Dim i       As Long

    For i = 1 To 20
        If fnBlnExists("Label" & i, UserForm1) Then
            Debug.Print UserForm1.Controls(CStr("Label" & i)).Name & " EXISTS"
        Else
            Debug.Print "Does Not exist!"
        End If
    Next i

End Sub

Public Function fnBlnExists(ControlName As String, ByRef FormCheck As UserForm) As Boolean

    Dim strTest As String
    On Error Resume Next
    strTest = FormCheck(ControlName).Name
    fnBlnExists = (Err.Number = 0)

End Function
```

Comment: Separate function might be an answer. And go for `Else Exit For`. It seems that it is either that or loop though all controls only when initialising the form and get the end value of the loop

Comment: @George - the idea of the code was to show how the `fnBlnExists` works. Thus, I have put the `debug.print`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest testing the existence in another procedure per below: -

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
Dim i As Long

i = 1
Do Until Not BoxExists(i)
    If Me.Conrtols("Box" & i).Value = MyCondition Then
        'Do stuff
    End If
    i = i + 1
Next
End Sub

Private Function BoxExists(ByVal LngID As Long) As Boolean
Dim Ctrl As Control

On Error GoTo ErrorHandle

Set Ctrl = Me.Controls("BoX" & LngID)
Set Ctrl = Nothing

BoxExists = True

Exit Function
ErrorHandle:
Err.Clear
End Function
```

In the above, `BoxExists` only returns true if the box does exists.

Answer (score 0):

You have taken an incorrect approach here.

If you want to limit the loop, you can loop only in the section your controls reside e.g. *Detail*. You can use the `ControlType` property to limit controls to TextBox.

```
Dim ctl As Control
For Each ctl In Me.Detail.Controls
    If ctl.ControlType = acTextBox Then
        If ctl.Value = MyCondition Then
            'do stuff
        End If
    End If
Next ctl
```

I believe the loop will be faster than checking if the control name exists through a helper function and an `On Error Resume Next`.

But this only a personal opinion.

Comment: Geia sou Kosta :). Thanks for the answer. That indeed works, but it loops through all controls. I also need an additional condition there so that `if ctl.controltype = acTextBox and LEFT(ctl.name, 3) = "Box" Then`. Which is why I only want to loop through controls named Box1,  Box2 and so on

Comment: Geia sou Giwrgo :). I cant help to ask why you need to loop only on the textboxes named "Box" . How many controls does the form have?

Comment: Not that many to make it a must. I am currently looping through all controls and no delay is noted. But I am new to programming and I am trying to make it a habit to work efficiently. So to answer your question a) I want to know if its possible and learn how to do and b) I want to make it a habit to at least think of more efficient ways, so that I can at least comment my code and revise at a later stage if needed. Bear in mind that by asking I also got the helpful comment of better form design and answer on collections as an alternative way of doing things